# Remove specific elements in Array of objects

Tags: java, arrays, jenkins, groovy

I have an Array of Object that is declared and look like this in Groovy:

```
def meal = [['Apple','Tomatoes', 'Coffee'],['Peach','Broccoli', 'Water'],['Orange','Peas', 'Pepsi'],['Banana','Beans', 'Coffee']]
```

How could I remove the third element in each object to my output look like this:

def meal = [['Apple','Tomatoes'],['Peach','Broccoli'],['Orange','Peas'],['Banana','Beans']]

I tried this but it returns a boolean (true)

```
def removeValue = meal.remove{a ->
a[2]
a}
```

Comment: `remove` function returns a boolean... https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove-java.lang.Object-

Answer (score 0):

def meal = [['Apple','Tomatoes', 'Coffee'],['Peach','Broccoli', 'Water'],['Orange','Peas', 'Pepsi'],['Banana','Beans', 'Coffee']]

meal.remove(meal[2])

println(meal) \ [[Apple, Tomatoes, Coffee], [Peach, Broccoli, Water], [Banana, Beans, Coffee]]

remove method creates a copy of given list without given index or condition(for closure) value

Answer (score 0):

`dropRight` and splicing and maybe others can be used to get rid of elements at the end of a vector and give you back a new vector.  Using the Spread-Operator `*.` to do that on all.

```
meal*.dropRight(1)
```

If you prefer modifying your original, there is also `removeLast`.

Comment: I am getting the following error: spread not yet supported for CPS transformation

Comment: Then you should tag your questions with jenkins. This answer stands for the "groovy" portion of your question.